# Combining two data frames with new column(s)

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two similar tables recording someones spending over 3 months.
From months 4-6 a new variable has been added.

```
df1 = data.frame(Month=c(1,2,3),Rent=c(132,123,234),Food=c(34,13,45))

df2 = data.frame(Month=c(4,5,6),Rent=c(111,212,231),Food=c(33,11,41),Fun=c(4,6,5))


> df1
  Month Rent Food
1     1  132   34
2     2  123   13
3     3  234   45

> df2
  Month Rent Food Fun
1     4  111   33   4
2     5  212   11   6
3     6  231   41   5
```

How can I combine/merge the two tables to look like this:

```
  Month Rent Food Fun
1     1  132   34  NA
2     2  123   13  NA
3     3  234   45  NA
4     4  111   33   4
5     5  212   11   6
6     6  231   41   5
```

Comment: `rbind(data.frame(df1, Fun = NA), df2)` or `dplyr::bind_rows(df1, df2)`

Comment: `data.table::rbindlist(list(df1, df2), use.names=T, fill=T)`  ( will return a `data.table`)

Comment: thanks, both solutions worked nicely!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use join family functions for such tasks in the `dplyr` package as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
full_join(df1, df2)
Joining by: c("Month", "Rent", "Food")
  Month Rent Food Fun
1     1  132   34  NA
2     2  123   13  NA
3     3  234   45  NA
4     4  111   33   4
5     5  212   11   6
6     6  231   41   5
```